# Kmail sets Subject, Sender, Receiver, Date to "Unkown". How to rebuild akonadi index?

Tags: kde, kde4, kmail

Mail that comes in is first as usual in the inbox - I am using POP3. But when I click on a mail, Kmail sets subject, sender, receiver, date to "Unkown". When I go online and at the messages from my provider's website I am able to verify tthat the messages are normal messages.

It seems I am having the issue mentioned in http://linux.derkeiler.com/Mailing-Lists/KDE/2009-02/msg00457.html
and it seems to be related to the bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/kdepim/+bug/50039 - but it is very old and supposed to be of Kmail1.

I considered following https://userbase.kde.org/KMail/FAQs_Hints_and_Tips#Problem:_You_are_losing_mail
but when I click on the folder or on "Folder" from the menu, I don't get anything like "rebuild index".

What can I do to fix this issue? How do I rebuild my kmail (or akonadi?) index?